# Need to concatenate data from bulk import

Tags: c#, datatable

How do I add two 00 onto "Host Key of Staff" in a DataColumn before it gets mapped to database table?

I have tried to do a covert on the data but its like I cant format it in a datatable.  Also tried to do for each loop to add extra 00 to field but couldnt get it to work either.

```
public partial class PageHours : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Upload and save the file
        string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

        string conString = string.Empty;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }
        conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

            //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange
                (new DataColumn[28] 
         { 
            new DataColumn("Name of Staff", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("StaffID", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Host Key of Staff", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Name of Department",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Description of Preferred Zone of Staff",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("User Text 2 of Staff",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Name of Programmes of Study of Module",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Description of Programmes of Study of Module",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Host Key of Locations",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Host Key of Module",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Description of Module",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Name",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Scheduled Start Date",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Teaching week pattern of Scheduled Activities as end date",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Section ID",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Description of Type",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Scheduled Start as day name",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Scheduled Start as start time",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Scheduled Finish as end time",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Duration as duration",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Part Time of Staff",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Taught Periods as duration",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Taught Periods Distinct as duration",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Teaching week pattern as week ranges",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Teaching week pattern as number of weeks",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Exported Weeks as week label range",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Scheduled by",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Date of Scheduling",typeof(string))   
        }
            );
            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);

            }
            excel_con.Close();

            string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PayrollPlusConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Data";

                    //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name of Staff", "Staff");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("StaffID", "StaffID");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Host Key of Staff", "HostKey");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name of Department", "Department");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Description of Preferred Zone of Staff", "Campus");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User Text 2 of Staff", "Grade");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name of Programmes of Study of Module", "AOS");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Description of Programmes of Study of Module", "AOSDescription");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Host Key of Locations", "Room");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Host Key of Module", "ModuleAOS");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Description of Module", "ModuleDescription");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Activity");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Scheduled Start Date", "StartDate");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Teaching week pattern of Scheduled Activities as end date", "EndDate");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Section ID", "SectionID");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Description of Type", "Type");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Scheduled Start as day name", "Day");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Scheduled Start as start time", "StartTime");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Scheduled Finish as end time", "EndTime");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Duration as duration", "Duration");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Part Time of Staff", "PartTime");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Taught Periods as duration", "TaughtPeriodsAsDuration");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Taught Periods Distinct as duration", "TaughtDistinct");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Teaching week pattern as week ranges", "WeekRanges");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Teaching week pattern as number of weeks", "TotalNoOfWeeks");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Exported Weeks as week label range", "WeeksThisRun");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Scheduled by", "ScheduledBy");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Date of Scheduling", "DateOfScheduling");

                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                    con.Close();

                    lblStatus.Text = "Upload Successful";

                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void DeleteData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection();
        con2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PayrollPlusConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con2.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con2;
        com.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [Data]";
        SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
        con2.Close();

        lblStatus.Text = "Data Deleted Successful, please upload for new month";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your `Host Key of Staff` column type should be integer? "Adding two 00" to some data presumes this data to be string one.

Comment: Or it could mean multiplying by 100, depending on whether she wants leading zeroes or trailing zeroes.

Comment: At the moment Host Key of Staff only holds 4 numbers for example 1234 but I need it to go into database like 001234

Comment: I have tried   foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows) and trying to edit the column that way but cant get it to work.

Comment: What exactly went wrong with your `foreach` attempt? By the way, where is the code related to it? You've shown all exept this one. And what is the type of `HostKey` column in database?

Comment: HostKey is sitting as int in database but can be changed if needed.         foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows)
                {
                    string HostKey = row.Field<int>("Host Key of Staff");
                    string HostKey2 = HostKey + "00";
                }

Comment: I will add code back into question, as it didnt work I thought better to leave it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an extension method like below

```
public static void Modify<T>(this DataColumn dataColumn, Func<object, T> toModify)
{
    foreach(DataRow dataRow in dataColumn.Table.Rows)
    {
        dataRow[dataColumn] = toModify(dataRow[dataColumn]);
    }
}
```

and then (i have used it for data time and pasting my code)

```
datatable.Columns["ColumnName"].Modify(
    value => DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
it should work on string
```

Comment: Thanks, would I just place the void Modify statement anywhere on page and then the datatable.columns part under excel_con.Close();

Comment: No, as you are trying to map the data table column to data base, so you need to modify the column before mapping. It means you have to use this where you are writing to data table. Or you can also use after writing every thing to data table and then modify the data column

Comment: Getting Error system.data.datcolumn does not contain a defination of Modify

Comment: and void Modify method needs to be in static class. I don't think so you working class is static. So better would be to add another static class, paste Modify extension method and then use it any where in the code where you want

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I have pasted your static void modify code at top off code then I have placed the second part of code datatable.columns .... under were the datatable is being populated

Comment: paste modify code out side of current class scope. It has to be in separate class

Comment: or if you can paste your complete class i can say where to paste it

Comment: I have pasted complete class into question part now, please help me.

Comment: its partial class i missed that at first read. Add another class to your project make it static and paste modify code there. Then after excel_con.Close(); you can use second part of code i.e. after filling data table. Hope this will help

Comment: glad it worked : ).. would you mind if you mart this as right answer?

Comment: There you go :) I would put this answer is useful but it says I need score of 15 to do that :( and somone has -1 my questions

Comment: Thanks, i dont see -1 :P

Answer (score 1):

First - it's better to change type of `Host Key of Staff` column of your `dtExcelData` from `int` to `string`, otherwise you will not be able to "prepend" your zeroes to the data it holds.

Second - in your loop you only getting data from DataRow but actually doesn't change it back. This loop should something like

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows) 
    row["Host Key of Staff"] = "00" + row["Host Key of Staff"].ToString();
```

Comment: I tried this but still going into database without 00.  I placed the loop statement in a few different areas but seems it never gets hit.

Comment: @Redheadinferno Oh, wait a minute.... I missed the fact of incorrect placement of your "post-processing" code. It should be placed after `excel_con.Close();` statement. And surely it will be hit there.

Comment: Thanks Andy, being hit now but data still going into database with 00.  Dont know why, any ideas? Sorry for being a pain

Comment: @Redheadinferno Pretty strange. Have you changed type of your `Host Key of Staff` datatable column  to string? Does it contains `"00" + your data` after loop over the rows? Check it with debugger.

Comment: I have changed it to string and it is adding the 00 to it when i debug it but then when get to columnmapping resorts back to orginal

Comment: Thanks Andy working now, had to change data type to varchar in database :)

Comment: @Redheadinferno shame on me - I missed "HostKey is sitting as int in database" in your comments to question. ;)

Comment: I'll forgive you this time cause your sooo amazing :p